# is ventricular depolarisation same as depolarisation during nerve impulse conduction?

Tags: physiology

Does the change in membrane charge accumulation occur in a similar way in heart and nerves cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depolarisation of nerve (here Purkinje fibres) causes Action Potential (bcoz of opening of voltage gated Na channels) which causes opening of Ca++ channels in membrane of heart muscle- results in ventricular contraction

So ventricular depolarisation is actually action potential in heart muscle of ventricles

So both terms are related
Ventricular depolarisation is a consequence of nerve impulse(depolarisation of nerve here Purkinje fibres )

Thnks
Ps: read bracket portion separately

Comment: thanks. I assume that the phenomenon takes place in the atria as well during arterial depolarisation .

Comment: True Correction atrial depolarisation not arterial

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER:** They are basically the same thing physically.

**LONG ANSWER:** Depolariation is a feature of any **excitable** tissue. Heart is no exception.

But the striking feature of Heart is that it can produce periodic depolarisation waves (With a defined Time Period). This ability of heart is due to certain modified *myocardial cells*, which are called conducting tissue of heart (SAN, AVN, Internodal Tracts, Bundle of His, Purkinje system).

The pattern of Action potential in different tissues is different. In **pacemaker tissues** we observe mainly a 'SLOW TYPE AP' (Due to **L**-Type $Ca^{2+}$ Channel); whereas the autorhythmicity is majorly due to an **HCN** Cation Channel. This eventually travels through **Gap Junction** from cell to cell to initiate depolarisation. Thus Depolarisation gradually moves from Atria to Ventricles (P $\longrightarrow$ Q-R-S Waves of ECG). In working myocardial cells AP is of 'FAST TYPE', due to VG $Na^+$ Channels)

Note that: Heart's oscillatory AP can be controlled (I mean modified) by ANS intervention.

> References: HCN Channels—Modulators of Cardiac and Neuronal
> Excitability Stefan Herrmann,* Sabine Schnorr, and Andreas Ludwig*
> Jens Schlossmann, Academic Editor ;
> Cardiology Explained. Ashley EA, Niebauer J. London: Remedica; 2004.